# How to automate a form completion with a bookmarklet when the form won't accept the data without a keystroke

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I'm using a bookmarklet in Chrome to enter data into a form, but on submit, the for clear itself if the input box hasn't had a keystroke in it. Any ideas on how to fix that? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that and everything else I could find, but nothing actually activates the input box and presses the key. I want to enter data like 1Password would (which activates the input box) to automate a process, but none of those triggers work. I'm now testing chrome extensions as an option.

Comment: While that wasn't the answer, your comment did make me realize how to fix it! 

Instead of keystrokes, I had to use this because it was a react form that must be listening to that event:

document.execCommand('insertText', false, newMobilePhone);

Thanks!